# Angular speed of an rotating ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, rotations

Consider an ellipsoid described the equation in cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$
$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{a^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1, \quad \text{where} \quad  a < c.$$
This ellipsoid is usually called the prolate spheroid.

Now we introduce rotation around the $z$ axis,the angular velocity $\omega$ at the point $x = a,y = a, z= 0$  is $\omega = v/a$. Can we find the formula for angular velocity at any point on the ellipsoid?

What my attempt was:
I thought that the angular velocity should be dependent only a the distance from the axis $z$, which I denoted $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.
From this i would get
$$\omega = \frac{v}{r} = \frac{v}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}},$$
where of course $x$, $y$ are points on the ellipsoid.

But this doesn't seem quite right with my intuition, since the angular velocity as a function of  $r$ will be the same in a sphere of radius $a$.
Did I make a mistake or is my intuition wrong?

Comment: Intuition seems wrong. The whole point of the concept of angular velocity of points belonging to a rigid body is that is is the same for all those points. Hint : the points $x,y$ at $z\not=0$ lie on a sphere centered around the $z$-axis. Their $\omega$ is the same as for the points at $z=0$. Their radius $r$ and their linear velocity $v$ is different.